# Add a blank line between orderings

Tags: sql

The following query:

```
SELECT t1.account, t1.group_name as "Group", t1.balance as Debit_Balance, t1.short_mkt_value as Short, t1.int_balance as "Long", t1.report_date as Date, t1.balance-t2.balance Daily_Change
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
ON t2.report_date=DATE_SUB(t1.report_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND t1.account=t2.account
where t1.group_name = "Group"
ORDER BY t1.report_date, t1.account
```

Produces the following data:

```
account Group   Debit_Balance   Short     Long         Date     Daily_Change
716-05  Carter   12861700      7892750   20754400    4/11/2018    -6119444
716-06  Carter   -8717010      10302500  1585470     4/11/2018    -1190944
716-07  Carter    7900390      20151900  28052300    4/11/2018     1303464
716-05  Carter    8689760       7064350  15754100    4/12/2018    -4171923
716-06  Carter  -10195500      12064200   1868720    4/12/2018    -1478470
716-07  Carter    6709190      20897900  27607100    4/12/2018    -1191199.5
```

How can I change my query so that after every set of accounts/ grouping there is a blank row?

Preferred Results:

```
account Group   Debit_Balance   Short     Long         Date     Daily_Change
716-05  Carter   12861700      7892750   20754400    4/11/2018    -6119444
716-06  Carter   -8717010      10302500  1585470     4/11/2018    -1190944
716-07  Carter    7900390      20151900  28052300    4/11/2018     1303464

716-05  Carter    8689760       7064350  15754100    4/12/2018    -4171923
716-06  Carter  -10195500      12064200   1868720    4/12/2018    -1478470
716-07  Carter    6709190      20897900  27607100    4/12/2018    -1191199.5
```

Comment: This should be done at the application level, not in the database.  SQL results sets are not "lines", they are rows, with all the columns defined for each row.

Comment: So there is no way to add a blank row after each grouping? This doesn't bode well for automation.

Comment: Which DBMS product and SQL client are you using? This might be possible with Oracle's `sqlplus`

Comment: @ChaseRaab: That is because SQL is designed for grabbing data, nothing more. And BTW your data is not grouped or where is your `group by` clause?

Comment: @jurgen not grouped but ordered, i have made the correction. I have seen examples of people selecting each column as "null" in order to achieve what I'm looking for, I just haven't got it to work.

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. Use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: @ChaseRaab . . .  "This doesn't bode well for automation.".  SQL has been used productively for a myriad of applications and analyses since the 1980s.  I think it has proven itself (yes, it could be improved, but then everything has room for improvement).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 0 as group_order, t1.account, t1.group_name as "Group", t1.balance as Debit_Balance, t1.short_mkt_value as Short, t1.int_balance as "Long", t1.report_date as Date, t1.balance-t2.balance Daily_Change
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
ON t2.report_date=DATE_SUB(t1.report_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND t1.account=t2.account
where t1.group_name = "Group"

UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 1 as group_order, '' as account, t1.group_name as "Group", 0 as Debit_Balance, 0 as Short, 0 as "Long", t1.report_date as  Date, 0 as Daily_Change
FROM table t1

ORDER BY group_order, Date, account
```

Thus you introduce distinct group values for group and date. Normally the group_order is 0 (to be first) and for the artificial group value it is 1 (to be last).